# Get a String from runRedis conn $ get "hello" - Haskell

Tags: haskell, redis

From Database.Redis I use runRedis conn $ get "hello", which is

```
runRedis conn $ get "hello"
  :: IO (Either Reply (Maybe Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString))
```

where

```
conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
```

But I want to convert the output to a String / ByteString, because I want to compare it to some other String.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you seen the hedis doc [Reply](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.7.10/docs/Database-Redis.html#t:Reply)? You will have to handle its cases appropriately. Is your question dealing with hedis or how to generally deal with this wrapped type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start when you're unsure of how things work in Haskell is to find their docs ([Hedis is here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.6.10/docs/Database-Redis.html#t:Redis)). You should look at the building blocks (i.e. functions) you need and their definitions. Anyway, on to your question.

It looks like you ultimately want something that always returns a `ByteString`, so let's move forward from where you are.

Basically, you're using the following functions: `runRedis` and `get`. The signatures look as follows:

`runRedis :: Connection -> Redis a -> IO a`

`get :: RedisCtx m f => ByteString -> m (f (Maybe ByteString))`

This looks a little confusing at first. I know `runRedis` is requiring me to give it a `Redis`-based routine and `get` requires some sort of `RedisCtx` (where the heck am I going to get that?). Well, if you traverse down the rabbit hole and take a look at the definition for `Redis a`, you will see that is supports a `RedisCtx` already:

`RedisCtx Redis (Either Reply)`

The first thing you should notice is that the `Redis` monad already binds both `m` and `f` of `RedisCtx` for you. In particular, it binds `m` to `Redis` and `f` to `Either Reply`. You should also notice that `Either` is only partially applied which is what provides you the flexibility to specify the return type in case of success (i.e. `Right`).

This makes our lives easier (you know, the [paradox of choice and all that](https://www.ted.com/talks/barry_schwartz_on_the_paradox_of_choice?language=en)) since we already have rigid types for many of our parameters. Now why did we go through this exercise? Equipped with this understanding, we can now see how to use the `get` method!

Since we're applying get from within the `Redis` monad, we understand that it has a bound `RedisCtx` and we know what those `m` and `f` values are. As such we arrive at a rigid type for `get` in our current use case:

`get :: RedisCtx Redis (Either Reply) => ByteString => Redis (Either Reply (Maybe ByteString))`

Well, that looks less ambiguous but maybe not exactly user-friendly. Omitting the `Redis` monad (since we're going to manipulate the output within it), you can now think of how to simply handle:

`Either Reply (Maybe ByteString)`

Now, that looks far less frightening since some of the very first things you learn in Haskell are how to operate on `Either` and `Maybe` types. Assuming we want to omit the failure case of `Either` (read: you should read the docs and see how to handle the cases of `Reply`), all of the sudden our handling code seems simple:

```
value <- get "..."
case value of
  Left _ -> return "Some error occurred"
  Right v -> return $ fromMaybe "Could not find key in store" v
```

**tl;dr** you're probably looking for something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main(main) where

import Data.ByteString
import Data.Maybe
import Database.Redis

onlyStringResult :: ByteString -> Redis ByteString
onlyStringResult key = do
  value <- get key
  case value of
    Left _ -> return "Some error occurred"
    Right v -> return $ fromMaybe "Could not find key in store" v

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
  result <- runRedis conn (onlyStringResult "hello")
  print result
```